# Difficult time understanding string pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, printf, c-strings, conversion-specifier

I am looking to learn C and having a really hard time grasping the concepts of string pointers (and just pointers in general).

I have the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()  
{   

    // char test[6] = "hello";
    char *test = "hello"; // test is a pointer to 'h'

    int size_of_test_pt = sizeof(test); // this is the size of a pointer? which is 8 bytes.
    int size_of_test = sizeof(*test); // this is the size of h, which is 1.

    printf("\nSize of pointer to test: %d\n", size_of_test_pt);  // prints 8
    printf("\nSize of test: %d\n", size_of_test);   // prints 1

    printf("\nPrint %s\n", test); // why does this print 'hello', I thought test was a pointer?
    printf("\nPrint %c\n", *test); // this is printing the first character of hello, I thought this would print hello.
    printf("\nPrint %i\n", *test); // this prints 104...is this ASCII for h

    return 0;
}
```

Everything makes sense until the last 3 print statements. If test is a pointer variable. Why does printf print out the word "hello" rather than an address?

For the `printf("\nPrint %c\n", *test)` call is it the right understanding that I am dereferencing test, which is an address and accessing the first element, then printing it to the screen?

Comment: *"If test is a pointer variable. Why does printf print out the word "hello" rather than an address?"* - because by using `%s` specifier you tell `printf` that it should take the pointer and print the string it points to.

Comment: The `%s` needs a pointer to dereference, which you give it. The `%c` needs one `char`, which you give it (automatically promoted to `int`), and the `%d` needs `int`, which is what the `char` is promoted to.

Comment: About *"the size of h, which is 1"*. It is the `sizeof(char)` which is 1, not `'h'`. The `sizeof('h')` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Not sure if I follow the last point. Why is sizeof('h') not equal to sizeof(char) when h is a char?

Answer (score 2):

The conversion specifier `%s` is designed to output strings and it expects as an argument a pointer expression of the type `char *` or `const char *` that points to the first character of a string that to be outputted.

In this case the function outputs all characters starting from the address pointed to by the supplied pointer until the terminating zero character `'\0'` is encountered.

If you want to output the value of such a pointer you need to write

```
printf("\nPrint %p\n", ( void * )test);
```

The conversion specifier `%c` is designed to output a single object of the type `char`.

Pay attention to that the pointer `test` points to the first character of the string literal `"hello"`. So dereferencing the pointer you will get the first character of the string literal.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *test = "hello";

    for ( ; *test != '\0'; ++test )
    {
        printf( "%c ", *test );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
h e l l o
```

The string literal is stored in memory as a character array containing the following elements

```
{ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If test is a pointer variable. Why does printf print out the word "hello" rather than an address?

In short, it's because the `%s` expects its parameter to be of type `char *`.

> For the printf("\nPrint %c\n", *test) call is it the right understanding that I am dereferencing test, which is an address and accessing the first element, then printing it to the screen?

Yes. The `%c` format specifier expects its parameter to be a `char`, and that's exactly what you get when you dereference a pointer to `char`. Furthermore, it knows to print that value as a character. In the following line, the `%i` parameter expects value of type `int`, and since `char` is a kind of `int`, it accepts that and prints the numeric value of the character (`h`) that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

In C a "string" is a sequence of characters, e.g. `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`. To indicate that the sequence is ending, the special value 0 is appended to the sequence.

If there were no such things as pointers, passing a string to a function would involve copying the entire sequence of characters. This is normally not practical, so instead we just pass on a reference (i.e. a pointer) telling where to find the first character of the string.

This is so commonly used that the pointer itself is sometimes referred to as a string even though it is really a pointer to a string. The string itself is the sequence of characters.

Think of a pointer like a bibliographic reference identifying a particular book. Including such a reference in a text is much more practical than inserting a copy of the entire book.